# Move a whole folder from its parent folder to another

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

Based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), i was able te move a file from a folder to another like so:

```
DriveItem file = await graphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Items[fileId]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(new DriveItem
    {
        Name = "New Name",
        ParentReference = new ItemReference
        {
            Path = "/drive/root:/New/Path"
        },
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        { 
            { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename" }
        }
    });
```

If I use the same logic to move a whole folder from its parent folder to another, I get this error:
\

> InvalidRequest: Must provide one of the following facets to create an item: Bundle, File, Folder, RemoteItem

If I add `Folder = new Folder{ }` in the DriveItem attributes, I get this error:

> InvalidRequest: Bad Argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually using the path of the folder and not its id.

```
DriveItem file = await graphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath(path)
    .Request()
    //...
```

That seemed to be, for an unclear reason, why the request failed. If I use the id (`.Items[fileId]`), it works.